# Ayuda adb: CreateFileW 'nul' failed: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. (2)

Tags: android-studio, adb

Estimados, necesito su ayuda.

Instale Android Studio 3.0.1 en windows 10 y resulta que no puedo lanzar ningun emulador, por mas de que los cree, estos no se visualizan y me sale el siguiente error:

10:10   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

10:10   adb: CreateFileW 'nul' failed: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. (2)

10:10   * failed to start daemon

10:10   error: cannot connect to daemon

10:10   'C:\Users\miUsername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

[image: Error]

He comprobado que el adb no esté corriendo y que tambien otros procesos escuchen el puerto 5037 como indican otros usuarios. Lo extraño es adb: CreateFileW 'nul' failed:

alguien tiene alguna idea?, llevo 2 días intentando solucionar el problema

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un archivo llamado adb que está en la carpeta

> C:\Users\ (Tu usuario)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Para solucionarlo descarga la carpeta plataform-tools y sustitúyela en ese enlace o si tienes el android studio instalado en otro ordenador copia esa carpeta en el ordenador que lo necesites.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

Comment: Gracias por responder Iñigo: Tengo esa carpeta, y tambien la he copiado desde otra computadora con android, inclusive la he descargado previamente del link que me diste anteriormente, sigue el mismo problema

Comment: Yo lo descargue, elimine el que ya tenía y copie este. Así se me soluciono, siento que a ti no te funcione.

Comment: Lo copíe de dos maquinas diferentes y nada, sale el mismo problema